Usage of つかない in this context?

The character is describing a special training the character in background did to obtain his powers now
In the first paragraphs she
野焼きで燃え盛る草原を悠然と歩みゆく有様は
Which is like walking on a field filled with fire
but then adds
仁王とも天女ともつかない神秘さだった
What does つかない here communicate? From context "don't have"?

This is a special usage of the verb つく. It always comes in the pattern AともBともつかない, and means "cannot be categorized as either A or B" or "one cannot tell if it's A or B".
明鏡国語辞典 explains this as the 27th definition:

27《「…とも…ともつかない」などの形で》…にも…にも属さない。中間的であいまいである。
「海の物とも山の物ともつかない代物だ」
「冗談とも真面目ともつかぬ表情」

See also: JLPT文法解説：～とも～ともつかない／ともいえない　N１

仁王とも天女ともつかない神秘さだった。
(His figure) possessed such a mysterious quality that one couldn't tell whether he was a 仁王 or a 天女.

